# Selenium C# Check if IWebElement exists using PageObject

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, pageobjects

Objective: Check if an element/IWebElement exists on the current page using PageObjects.

I am aware of the fact that you can use something like:

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("foo")));
```

But as i use PageObjects i dont want to use the id/xpath etc again. I am currently using the method beneath to check whether an element exists. But to do this fast i first set the Implicit wait and after i reset it to the default value. It works quite well, but it feels dirty.

I found some other older post . But this didn't provide any solution to me yet. Hope you can help!

PageObject:

```
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "errorMessage")]
    public IWebElement btnSubmit { get; set; }
```

Calling the method:

```
CheckElementExists(errorMessage))
```

The method;

```
public bool CheckElementExists(IWebElement pageObject)
    {
        Browser.getDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        try
        {
            return pageObject.Equals(pageObject);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Browser.getDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would say that your solution is the standard solution. The question is how long/short time you should be waiting for an element (that should not exist)? No standard answer, but its definitively a trade-off between execution time and test reliability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put the implicit wait on 0 seconds now. and use explicit waits everywhere. So its working quite nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experince with C# but I think it's very similar to JAVA and so you can conver the following JAVA code in C#.

if want to write function just to check if element exist, this is how you can do it.

```
public boolean isElementExisit(WebElement element){
    try{
        element.getTagName();
        return true;
    }catch (NoSuchElementException){
        return false;
    }
}
```

if you want to write something which requires to wait, then you can use fluent wait.

```
public void waitUntilElementIsPresent(WebElement element, int timeout){
        Wait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        wait.until(new Function() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(Object o) {
                element.getTagName();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to have a look at this fluent wait! Your java solution looks quite similar to my C# solution. :D

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do the `FindElement` in the try based on the `id` you want to use. If it finds it then it will proceed to returning `true`, but if it catches the `NoSuchElementException` then it will return `false`:

```
bool CheckIfItExists(string ElementId)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.Id(ElementId));
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking of this as well, but i am not solely using ID's, for some page objects i use Xpaths or Classnames.

Comment: Try not to let Exceptions happen in your code, cause it costs a lot. Instead use something like this `int result = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@id=\'user_email\']")).Count; if(result > 0) { //do something } `

Answer (score 0):

**To assert presence of an element,** with C# and [NUnit](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.True.html)

```
Assert.IsTrue(
  btnSubmit.Displayed,
  "Submit button should be displayed"
);
```

**To assert absence of an element**, I really like [NUnit's Assert.throw](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.Throws.html) syntax.

```
Assert.Throws<NoSuchElementException>(
  () => btnSubmit.Contains(""),
  "Accessing Submit button should throw NoSuchElementException"
);
```